# Add Two Zeroes in front of file sequence number

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-rename

I'm fairly new to python and I want to format my filenaming with an extra two zeros infront for single digit and a single zero for 2 digit numbers depending on the file sequence.

My current file naming just renames my file like
ex. 1930L1.mp3

I want it to be 1930L001.mp3

Here is my code

```
import os

folderPath = r'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\1930'
fileSequence = 1

for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):
    os.rename(folderPath + '\\' + filename, folderPath + '\\' + '1930L' + str(fileSequence) + '.mp3')
    fileSequence +=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) method to add leading zeroes to your number:

```py
fileSequenceString = str(fileSequence).zfill(3)
```

As parameter value should be final output string length, so in this case it's `3`.

In your code snippet:

```py
os.rename(folderPath + '\\' + filename, folderPath + '\\' + '1930L' + str(fileSequence).zfill(3) + '.mp3')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Python f-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) as follows

```py
for i in range(0, 10):
  num = f"{i:03d}"
  fn = "1930L" + num + ".mp3"
  print(fn)
```

that produces

```
1930L000.mp3
1930L001.mp3
1930L002.mp3
1930L003.mp3
1930L004.mp3
1930L005.mp3
1930L006.mp3
1930L007.mp3
1930L008.mp3
1930L009.mp3
```

where

- number `0` is for leading zero,
- number `3` is for number of digits,
- letter `d` is for decimal integer.